# Creating a data entry screen from a list in Tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to generate data entry screen from a list

I have created the essential functionality of what I'm going for here:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("example")
root.geometry("1200x900")

def clicked():
    data = (foo_entry.get(), 
        bar_entry.get())
    success_label = Label(root, text = "Entries Stored!").grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    values_stored_label = Label(root, text = str(data)).grid(row = 4, column = 2)

foo_label= Label(root ,text = "foo").grid(row = 0,column = 0)
bar_label= Label(root ,text = "bar").grid(row = 1,column = 0)

foo_entry = Entry(root) 
foo_entry.grid(row =  0, column = 1) 
bar_entry = Entry(root) 
bar_entry.grid(row =  1, column = 1) 
submit_button = Button(root,text = "Submit Entries", command = lambda: clicked())
submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 2)



root.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to do now is create a script that creates this same data entry screen when it's supplied a list of names. so given:

```
entries = ['foo','bar']
```

I essentially want to generate the same screen from the earlier example it creates the window and labels and grids just fine but retrieving the input data is throwing up a key error at the `Entry.get()`.
The code is below:

```
entries = ['foo','bar']
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("example")
root.geometry("1200x900")

def clicked():
    readout= ''
    for i in range(len(entries)):
        entryget = {entries[i]: entry[entries[i]].get()}
        readout += entryget[entries[i]]
    success_label = Label(root, text = "Entries Stored!")
    success_label.grid(row = len(entries)+2,column = 1)
    submit_label = Label(root, text = readout)
    submit_label.grid(row = len(entries)+3,column = 1)


for i in range(len(entries)):
    label = {entries[i]: Label(root ,text = entries[i])}
    labelgrid = {entries[i]:label[entries[i]].grid(row = i,column = 0)}
    entry = {entries[i]: Entry(root)}
    entrygrid = {entries[i]: entry[entries[i]].grid(row = i, column = 1)}
 
submit_button = Button(root,text = "Submit Entries", command = lambda: clicked())
submit_button.grid(row = len(entries)+1, column = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

The error that pops up is:

```
 File "examp2.py", line 11, in clicked
    entryget = {entries[i]: entry[entries[i]].get()}
KeyError: 'foo'
```

Any help would be awesome. If there's a more efficient way of doing this too please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. The part you are missing is that you need to make the dictionary  or list to store the entries before the loop, not in it. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked():
    results = [entry.get() for entry in entries.values()]
    readout= ', '.join(results)
    success_label = Label(root, text = "Entries Stored!")
    success_label.grid(column = 1) # row defaults to the next available one
    submit_label = Label(root, text = readout)
    submit_label.grid(column = 1)

LABELS = ['foo','bar']
entries = {} # initialize an empty dictionary to fill later

root = Tk()
root.title("example")
root.geometry("1200x900")

for i, text in enumerate(LABELS):
    label = Label(root, text = text) # no need to store the label
    label.grid(row = i,column = 0)
    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.grid(row = i, column = 1)
    entries[text] = entry # store this entry in the global dictionary

submit_button = Button(root,text = "Submit Entries", command = clicked) # don't need lambda 
submit_button.grid(column = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that solved my issue beautifully